# How to deploy FlexiPage with error: Invalid property [enableActionsInNative] in component [force:highlightsPanel]

Tags: deployment, workbench

We have made many changes via Lighting App Builder to Lighting Pages (FlexiPages). When we try to deploy these changes using Gearset, we get the error:

```
Invalid property [enableActionsInNative] in component [force:highlightsPanel]
```

According to [this post](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9064S000000D9PtQAK), the reason is we are deploying from a Sandbox on Winter '21 to an org running Summer '20 release.

How do I deploy this change?

Comment: In your Gearset deploy, what version did you tell gearset to use in the Compare?  If highest common, then this shouldn't happen.  If V50, then error would happen.  Also, no hyperlink in the phrase ...this post ...

Comment: I tested in Gearset and once this feature is "on" it shows up in all APIs you use in the compare - hence, my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to get this done, although he solution is less than ideal.

I performed some minor surgery on the XML for the FlexiPages to remove the node in the XML which specifies the `enableActionsInNative` property, and then used Workbench to perform the deploy. This time the FlexiPages didn't result in an error, and deployed just fine.

Here's the XML I removed from each of the FlexiPages:

```
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>enableActionsInNative</name>
    <value>false</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

In order to do this, you must retrieve the metadata using whatever tool you are used to working with, then remove the entire node surrounding the `enableActionsInNative` property.

Perhaps there are other, more elegant ways to get the deployment to go through, but this one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes fix this by downgrading your API to match the target assuming it's a property that has simply changed with an update.

Salesforce will return the `flexipage` with the properties according to that release/API you're retrieving/deploying as.

In this case, the property `enableActionsInNative` is related to Dynamic Forms and is new so it seems it always returns once it's been turned on. It's specifically enabling dynamic actions from the Highlights Panel for Salesforce Mobile app just as a FYI. Removing it manually (as you did) is probably the best option and safe to do if you're not looking to move that.

[image]